# Verificar se há objeto em instancia

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.0

Gostaria de saber como verifico se há objeto em variável no Python.

Eu tentei assim:

```
try:
  select_me = User.select_me(request)
  select_random = User.select_random(request, 3)

  me = select_me.username
  random = select_random.username
  gender = select_random.gender
except:
  me = 'Error'
  random = 'Error'
  gender = 'Error'
```

Mas creio eu, que dá pra dar uma ajeitada nisso aí, por exemplo, "encurtar"

No Python, existe alguma função para verificar se existe um objeto dentro dessa variável?

PS: Sem o tratamento com `try` e `except` ele me lança:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'

no PHP um `if (is_object(...))` resolveria, e no Python?

Algo com `if` ou `else` ou até alguma função nativa do Python, tem como?

Comment: Quais são os possíveis retornos da função `User.select_me`? Um objeto `User` ou `None`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, retornos, username, name, lastname...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a chamada pode retornar um objeto ou `None`, você compara verificando se o objeto retornado é `None` com o operador `is`:

```py
select_me = User.select_me(request)
if select_me is None:
   me, random, gender = "Error"
else:
   ...
```

Note que a comparação com uso de `is` só deve ser feita em casos especiais - como o None, ou quando se usa a [Sentinel Pattern](https://python-patterns.guide/python/sentinel-object/) . Se for uma chamada que pode devolver uma string vazia, ou uma lista vazia você simplesmente verifica o "truth value" do objeto retornado - (qualquer container vazio ou numeral == 0, ou None vai ser `False` em Python - todos os outros objetos são `True`) - nesse caso, a expressão no if é o próprio objeto (ou o `not` do objeto):

```py
select_me = User.select_me(request)
if not select_me:
   me, random, gender = "Error"
else:
   ...
```

No caso de você não saber se uma variável já foi definida - por exemplo, se ela é definida só dentro de um bloco de `if` que não foi executado - o recomendado em Python é definir a variável antes do `if` - ou seja,
em vez de:

```py
if tudo_ok():
    conexao = conectar()

...
# não há uma verificação para "undefined"
conexao.usar
```

fazer:

```py
conexao = None
if tudo_ok():
    conexao = conectar()

...
if conexao is not None:
    conexao.usar
```

Para esse caso, (da variável não estar definida), funcionaria colocar o código que vai usar a variável que você não sabe se está definida em um bloco `try` e capturar a exceção `NameError` na cláusula `except` - mas isso não é uma boa prática.